# Firebird Insert Distinct Data Using ZeosLib and Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, firebird, zeos

I'm using Zeos 7, and Delphi 2009 and want to check to see if a value is already in the database under a specific field before I post the data to the database.

Example:  Field Keyword
Values of Cheese, Mouse, Trap

```
tblkeywordKEYWORD.Value = Cheese
```

What is wrong with the following?  And is there a better way?

```
zQueryKeyword.SQL.Add('IF NOT EXISTS(Select KEYWORD from KEYWORDLIST ='''+
  tblkeywordKEYWORD.Value+''')INSERT into KEYWORDLIST(KEYWORD) VALUES ('''+
  tblkeywordKEYWORD.Value+'''))');
zQueryKeyword.ExecSql;
```

I tried using the unique constraint in IBExpert, but it gives the following error:

> Invalid insert or update value(s): object columns are
>   constrained - no 2 table rows can have duplicate column values.
>   attempt to store duplicate value (visible to active transactions) in unique index "UNQ1_KEYWORDLIST".

Comment: Your SQL statement as posted contains unmatched parens, so it's unlikely you get the error that you show - Zeos should throw a syntax error instead.

Comment: That error message is from trying to do the unique constraint in IBExpert, not from the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use UPDATE OR INSERT or MERGE statements:

```
update or insert into KEYWORDLIST (KEYWORD) values(:KEYWORD) matching(KEYWORD)
```

For details check the following documents in your Firebird installation folder:

- doc\sql.extensions\README.update_or_insert.txt
- doc\sql.extensions\README.merge.txt

Comment: Dmitry, would have bought your components, but over my current budget.

Comment: Well, you always may ask for a discount.